# How to apply dependent fileds filters in appengine datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

Representation of my datastore:

```
key|first|second|
-----------------
xys|55   |34
-----------------
kow|32   |67
```

If I have to write a `sql` query then it should be like this:

```
select * from x where first > second + 20;
```

How could I write it in `appengine datastore`? Is there any way to achieve it by `Query.FilterPredicate`?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact that all appengine queries must be efficient. I cant see how to avoid a full scan using datastore indexes of those two properties which is not efficient.
the solution is to also store the difference (first-second) then you can filter on the difference > 20.